# What are the common security flaws I need to look for?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, security, sql

As a wannabe WP plugin developper, what are the main security flaws/holes I should look for?

I'm about to create a new plugin with a configuration panel (ie input fields and stuff). What should I be concerned about?

For example, is data sanitization such a big deal since it's in the /wp-admin/ area? Could someone malicious directly hit my plugin page and send POST requests or something like that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 16):

Here is a modified checklist, based on my current (work-in-progress) settings/data security checklist used for reviewing Themes (the principles should be no different for Plugins than they are for Themes):

1. Plugins should prefix all options, custom functions, custom variables, and custom constants with plugin-slug.
2. Plugins should implement Plugin Options and Plugin Settings pages deliberately, rather than relying on copy-and-paste scripts from website tutorials, such as the ones below, which are outdated, and do not include proper data security:

   - http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/wordpress/how-to-create-an-options-page-for-your-wordpress-theme/
   - http://wpshout.com/create-an-awesome-wordpress-theme-options-page-part-1
3. Plugins should use the `add_options_page()` function to add the Plugin Settings Page to the `Settings` menu, rather than using `add_menu_page()` to add a top-level menu.
4. Plugins should use an appropriate *capability* (e.g. `manage_options`) for the capability to add the settings page.
5. Plugins should save options in a single array, rather than create multiple options for the settings page. The use of the Settings API (see below) would handle this.
6. Plugins should use the Settings API(see below) to get and save form input data rather than rely on `$_POST` and `$_REQUEST` data directly.
7. For checkboxes and select options, Plugins should use the `checked()` and `selected()` functions for outputting `checked="checked"` and `selected="selected"`, respectively.
8. **Plugins should validate and sanitize all untrusted data before entering data into the database, and should escape all untrusted data before being output in the Settings form fields and before being output in the Theme template files:**

   - http://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation
9. Plugins should use `esc_attr()` for text inputs and `esc_html()` (or `esc_textarea()` in WP 3.1) for textareas.
10. Plugins should explicitly provide Settings-page nonce checking, if not using the Settings API:

    - http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces
11. It is also highly recommended that Plugins use the Settings API, which is easier to use, more secure, and takes care of a lot of the hard work of settings pages:

    - http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API

For a good tutorial on using the Settings API, see:

- http://www.chipbennett.net/2011/02/17/incorporating-the-settings-api-in-wordpress-themes/
- http://planetozh.com/blog/2009/05/handling-plugins-options-in-wordpress-28-with-register_setting/

If you want to check out a theme with a secure and solidly-coded theme settings page, check out this theme:
http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/coraline

Comment: And I should add: if anyone sees anything missing from the list, *please comment*, so that I can add it to the checklist, to help improve the security review for Themes!

Comment: Wow, great list, thanks. I wonder if its worth making this question a community wiki and making each of these points their own answer to better allow discussion and elaboration?

Comment: I'd be fine with that, but don't want to hijack the original poster's question (unless that's how things are done on StackExchange? I'm still new here...).

Comment: I dunno either... leave it up to moderators discretion, I guess. This seems like it would make a great wiki question, as its so important and best practices are still being working out. @Rarst?

Comment: I could create a new Question, if need be?

Comment: Community wiki makes sense to me. New question, one thing per answer (easier to discuss, vote and edit), get mod to set community wiki status (and since I am not diamond-ized yet, bug someone else about latter ;)

Comment: Okay, just added a new question; but I don't seem to be able to enter any answers...

Comment: And now all answers have been added. Whew, that took a bit of work. :)

Comment: @ChipBennet Why do you recommend `add_settings_page` rather then `add_menu_page` for plugin settings page? For usability issues, i agree with you to list all plugin related settings in one page under the "Tools" section. But this isn't really a security issue, right? You can just add the $capability parameter to the `add_menu_page` function. For bigger plugins, it is still recommended to use your own top-level page with some sub pages. Or did i missed something?

Comment: @Roman Wunsche: here are the [official Codex recommendations for menu locations](http://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Menus#Determining_Location_for_New_Menus). Plugin Settings pages go under "Settings". Only Plugins that provide novel, extraordinary functionality should be adding top-level menu entries.

Comment: To wit: "It is rare that a plugin would require the creation of a top-level menu. If the plugin introduces an entirely new concept or feature to WordPress, and needs many screens to do it, then that plugin may warrant a new top-level menu. Adding a top-level menu should only be considered if you really need multiple, related screens to make WordPress do something it was not originally designed to accomplish. Examples of new top-level menus might include job management or conference management."

Comment: @ChipBennett Sure, but the question it "security" not "usability".

Comment: @Roman Wunsche: again: as stated at the beginning of my Answer, these were taken from the current checklist I use for Theme Review. If correct menu placement is too orthogonal for the current topic, feel free to ignore it. :)

Comment: It shouldn't be a critism, just a clarifying question ;). It could have been that `add_menu_page` give a user more rights by default, so I have to ask. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Thank you!! That was exactly the kind of checklist I was looking for.

Answer (score 11):

There are two aspects to this:

1. **Basic principles.**

   - Whatever is written into database should be checked for SQL injects.
   - Whatever is printed to screen should be checked that it doesn't print harmful JavaScript.
   - Whenever someone does something it should be checked that it was his intention to do so and he has appropriate capability.
   - There are many many more things that you or me either won't ever think to check for.
2. **Specifics.**

   - Modern WordPress takes security seriously and aims to make it easy for developers.
   - So for most of things you want to do there is most likely a way to get it done with WP APIs.
   - So whatever you are doing your first step would be to fine and study appropriate API.
   - The further you are from common and simple functionality the more complex things you will need to study and implement.

Answer (score 1):

1. Add `defined('ABSPATH') or die('Access denied');` at every plugin's script that used by wordpress directly
2. Add empty index.php file at every directory
3. Add .htaccess in plugin directory with needed instructions for prevent direct access to certain plugin's files.