# What Are Security Best Practices for WordPress Plugins and Themes?

Tags: plugins, themes, security

[As suggested in this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/13501/3966), I am adding this topic as a new question, for community discussion/voting regarding best-practices for Plugin/Theme security.

Here is the starting checklist, based on my current (work-in-progress) settings/data security checklist used for reviewing Themes (the principles should be no different for Plugins than they are for Themes).

If you want to check out a theme with a secure and solidly-coded theme settings page, check out this theme:
http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/coraline

Comment: If someone with the appropriate privileges wouldn't mind making this a community wiki?

Comment: To get a question in wiki mode [a mod needs to tag the question appropriately](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts/11741#11741), i've flagged it for mod attention, it's a just a matter of time now.. :)

Comment: What's so special about coraline? Imo there are still ways to get in. I'd suggest to link anons A insted: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/13539/what-are-security-best-practices-for-wordpress-plugins-and-themes/13548#13548

Comment: There may be nothing particularly special about Coraline. It's simply the one we currently point Theme developers to, when reviewing Themes, because it was the example given by Justin Tadlock, who did many of the initial security-specific Theme reviews. I'd offer up Oenology also as a good example, but I don't want to come across as trying to pimp my own Theme. :)

Answer (score 13):

### Use Nonces (when not using Settings API)

Plugins and Themes should explicitly provide Settings-page nonce checking, if not using the Settings API:

- [WordPress Nonces (Codex)](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces)
- [WordPress Nonces (Mark Jaquith)](http://markjaquith.wordpress.com/2006/06/02/wordpress-203-nonces/)
- [Improving security in WordPress plugins using Nonces (Vladimir Prelovac)](http://www.prelovac.com/vladimir/improving-security-in-wordpress-plugins-using-nonces)
- [5 tips for using AJAX in WordPress > 3. Use nonces and check for permission (Gary Cao)](http://www.garyc40.com/2010/03/5-tips-for-using-ajax-in-wordpress/#nonce-permission)

Answer (score 12):

### Sanitize, validate and escape data

**Sanitize anything that could get in and out of (!) the database both front end and back end!**

Plugins and Themes should perform proper data validation:

1. **Validate** and **sanitize** all untrusted data before entering data
   into the database
2. **Escape** all untrusted data before being output in the Settings form
   fields
3. **Escape** all untrusted data before being output in the Theme template
   files

   - [Data Validation (Codex)](http://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation)

Plugins and Themes should use `esc_attr()` for text inputs and `esc_html()` or `esc_textarea()` for text areas.

Also available from the WordPress API is `esc_url()`, `esc_url_raw()`, `esc_js()` and `wp_filter_kses()`.

**Bad example:**

```
<?php $url = 'javascript:pwnd()'; ?>
<a href="<?php echo $url; ?>">anchor</a>
```

**Good example:**

```
<a href="<?php echo esc_url($url); ?>">anchor</a>
```

Here is a great video of Mark Jaquith explaining the usage of the escaping functions:

- [Theme & Plugin Security](http://wordpress.tv/2011/01/29/mark-jaquith-theme-plugin-security/)

Comment: Sanitize on the way in, escape on the way out.. :)

Answer (score 9):

### Only use $_GET / $_POST / $_REQUEST carefully and when better APIs are unavailable

Plugins and Themes should use the Settings API to get and save form input data rather than rely on `$_POST` and `$_REQUEST` data directly.

Comment: Always treat $_POST, $_REQUEST, and $_GET as unsafe. Sanitize and whitelist values from those arrays and put them into your own variables. Never sanitize values coming from the user and put them back into $_POST.

Comment: Always check that the key that you need to use is set in the appropriate array. isset() is your friend :)

Answer (score 9):

## Use `$wpdb->prepare`

When building custom queries via the `$wpdb` object, always use [`$wpdb->prepare`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpdb_Class#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks) to fill placeholders with values instead of writing the queries with data mixed with SQL code, as the `mysql_*` family functions have wrongly taught everyone.

Comment: `$wpdb->prepare` is **not** the same as prepared statements.

Answer (score 8):

### Be careful with PHP functions that might be used to run malicious code

A nice read for anybody writing PHP: [Exploitable PHP functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115559/exploitable-php-functions) on StackOverflow.

### Use [Theme Modification API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Modification_API)

Themes should use [`set_theme_mod()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/set_theme_mod) and related functions **not** an self invented name scheme.
The theme_mod API is a specialized layer for the settings API; it guarantees unique names, pushes all options into **one** array and is – from my experience – much easier to handle. Plus, it offers standardized filters for plugins – which is good for interoperability.

### Avoid enabled [`register_globals`](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php)

Don’t rely on `register_globals = on`. A *Pro Theme* which my last client bought does exactly this. I could hack any site using this theme in 5 minutes …
ThimbThumb did this too (and still does?).

### Do not create files with unnecessary wide access permissions

Don’t create files with too liberate access permissions.

### Use SSL where available

Point your *Share on Twitter/Facebook/Anything* links to the HTTPS URI if available. Your reader’s security is important too.

Comment: Can you elaborate on `set_theme_mod()`, especially, how properly to combine it with Settings API usage?

Comment: @Chip Bennett I have added some information to my answer.

Comment: Can you break down this mini-list in smaller more specific answers? Easier to manage community wiki in smaller chunks. TIA

Comment: Chip: The Theme mod system doesn't integrate too well with the Settings API. I'll write up a post explaining how to do it right sometime soon.

Answer (score 7):

### Save data in single array

Plugins and Themes should save options in a single array, rather than create multiple options for the settings page. The use of the Settings API would handle this.

Answer (score 6):

### Check for appropriate capability when adding and outputting settings pages

Plugins should use an appropriate *capability* (e.g. `manage_options`) for the capability to add the settings page.

Themes should use `edit_theme_options` as the appropriate *capability* to add the settings page.

- [Roles and Capabilities (Codex)](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities)

Comment: **Small but important note:** You can't use `edit_theme_options` with the settings API though, option submission is hard-coded to require `manage_options` in order to submit updates. Related Trac ticket can be found [here](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/14365).

Comment: True, but 1) that will only impact Editors, not Admins; and 2) hopefully that will be addressed soon, via the linked Trac ticket.

Comment: There's always the possibility of a custom role or a regular role being given the `edit_theme_options` cap to, i thought it might be handy to point out that the settings API in it's current state is only usable by roles with the `manage_options` capability.

Answer (score 5):

### Use up-to-date tutorials and information

Plugins & Themes should both implement Options and Settings pages deliberately and **not** rely on copy-and-paste website tutorials which are outdated and do not include proper data security, such as those listed below.

Examples of what **not to do**:

- [How to create an options page for your wordpress theme](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/wordpress/how-to-create-an-options-page-for-your-wordpress-theme/) (1stwebdesigner.com)
- [Create an awesome WordPress theme options page part 1](http://wpshout.com/create-an-awesome-wordpress-theme-options-page-part-1) (wpshout.com)

Comment: I added a little emphasized text in to indicate the links are examples of what not to do, as it's easy to skim through the information and click the links without reading the paragraph that preceeds them. Also made the answer a little prettier whilst i was there... ;)

Comment: This could use bit of explanation what exactly example tutorials are doing in a wrong and/or old way.

Answer (score 4):

### Use Settings API

Plugins and Themes should use the Settings API, which is easier to use, more secure, and takes care of a lot of the hard work of settings pages:

- [Settings API (Codex)](http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API)

For a good tutorials on using the Settings API, see:

- [Incorporating the Settings API in WordPress Themes (Chip Bennett)](http://www.chipbennett.net/2011/02/17/incorporating-the-settings-api-in-wordpress-themes/)
- [Handling Plugins Options in WordPress with register_setting() (Ozh Richard)](http://planetozh.com/blog/2009/05/handling-plugins-options-in-wordpress-28-with-register_setting/)
- [WordPress Settings API Tutorial (Otto)](http://ottopress.com/2009/wordpress-settings-api-tutorial/)

Comment: See my comment on [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/13539/what-are-security-best-practices-for-wordpress-plugins-and-themes/13543#13543) with regards to the settings API and theme options.

Answer (score 1):

### Prefix function and variable names

Plugins should prefix all options, custom functions, custom variables, and custom constants with plugin-slug.

Themes should prefix all options, custom functions, custom variables, and custom constants with theme-slug.

Comment: I would extend this to all class names as well as names of custom objects like post_types and taxonomies.

Answer (score 1):

For checkboxes and select options, Plugins and Themes should use the `checked()` and `selected()` functions for outputting `checked="checked"` and `selected="selected"`, respectively.

Comment: Not really a security thing, unless I am missing something.  Still highly convenient and good to use. :)

Comment: Well, perhaps and perhaps not. I've seen a LOT of custom code for accomplishing the same thing. More code spaghetti = more opportunities to introduce security risks. :)

Comment: Bennet - from mailing with toscho some days ago - i guess i can say it for both of us - most simple functions for that are much easier to read & understand than those functions. I'm not down-, but also not upvotings this. Imo this shouldn't be part of the core, as it doesn't add any value.

Comment: I'm curious what you guys came up with that's easier than `checked( $theme_options['whatever_option'] )` or `checked( 'some_value' == $theme_options['whatever_option'] )`. I don't know how it gets more succinct than that?

Answer (score 1):

Use [wp_safe_redirect()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_safe_redirect) instead of calling php's header() function directly when directing to a page on the same domain.

Answer (score 0):

### Add settings pages to appropriate sections of admin menu

Plugins should use the `add_options_page()` function to add the Plugin Settings Page to the `Settings` menu, rather than using `add_menu_page()` to add a top-level menu.

Themes should use the `add_theme_page()` function to add the Theme Settings Page to the `Appearance` menu, rather than using `add_menu_page()` to add a top-level menu.