# Secure Validation of wp_editor in Theme Options

Tags: tinymce, security, theme-options, wp-editor

So I just found this great [WPSE thread about security for themes/plugins](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/13530/9844). It answered most of my questions but it was created before the new `wp_editor()` function was built.

I have two TinyMCE editors on my Theme Options and I'm wondering whether I need to use `esc_html()` or `esc_textarea()` in a validation callback before saving the theme option. It seems to me that TinyMCE takes care of a lot of that stuff (as well as the Settings API security that's taken care of), but there's still not a lot of documentation out there about `wp_editor()`.

Any resources and answers appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`esc_html()` and `esc_textarea()` are, appropriate to their names, escaping functions and really meant for display rather than sanitizing or validating. I would use `wp_kses()` or `wp_kses_post()` (which is just `wp_kses()` with the global `$allowedposttags`) to sanitize input from a `wp_editor()` field before saving.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @helenhousandi. For you (or anyone else reading this), it seems that @bueltge's answer implies that TinyMCE is essentially doing what `wp_kses()` does already so it's not necessary. But I don't know the answer (hence the question in the first place), so I'm not the best judge of that.

Comment: TinyMCE is capable of doing this, but does not by default. Also realize that a user could switch to using the area as a textarea (HTML mode) instead, so you always need to be sanitizing and validating data on the server side.

Answer (score 6):

The TinyMCE has an Filter for all allowed tags. You can change the tags, there are set in standard for your options and the editor filter the tags. Its not necassary, that you filter after save.

Example for enhanced tags:

```
function fb_change_mce_options( $initArray ) {
    // Comma separated string od extendes tags
    // Command separated string of extended elements
    $ext = 'pre[id|name|class|style],iframe[align|longdesc|name|width|height|frameborder|scrolling|marginheight|marginwidth|src]';
    if ( isset( $initArray['extended_valid_elements'] ) ) {
        $initArray['extended_valid_elements'] .= ',' . $ext;
    } else {
        $initArray['extended_valid_elements'] = $ext;
    }
    // set tiny paramter verify_html
    $initArray['verify_html'] = true;
    return $initArray;
}
add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'fb_change_mce_options' );
```

You can also filter the tags, all tags inside the array `$initArray` is allowed.
Its easy to kill tags fromthe array.
`unset( $initArray['pre'] )`

read the items inside the array via `var_dump( $initArray );`

Best